# How to replace default branches in GitVersion config?

Tags: gitversion

If you run `GitVersion /showConfig` with no config file present, you'll see that there are a bunch of default branch configs. If you set up a branch config in the config file:

```
branches:
  example:
    regex: "example"
    source-branches: []
```

then show config will show this at the beginning of the branch list. If you set up a branch with the same name as an existing default branch config:

```
  master:
   increment: Minor
```

then show config will merge this setting with the default master branch and move it to the top:

```
branches:
  master:
    mode: ContinuousDeployment
    tag: ''
    increment: Minor
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: ^master$
    source-branches:
    - develop
    - release
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
    is-mainline: true
    pre-release-weight: 55000
```

This could be handy sometimes, but other times it just annoyingly means that your branch has an unexpected config or that your regex fails to match and one of the other default branch configs matches.

*How can I get GitVersion to completely replace its default branch configs with the config I give and not merge either the list or the settings of each branch?*

Answer (score 0):

GitVersion uses all the settings shown when it calculates the Semantic version for your project on a given branch.

When you provide your own configuration, what you're really doing is overriding the default configuration. If you don't provide an overridden configuration value for an item in a branch configuration, the default configuration value for that branch is used. So even though you don't provide it, it's inherited. The alternative is for you to specify each and every setting for your branch configurations to completely override and customize how GitVersion works for you.

Again, this is necessary, because these configurations are used whenever GitVersion calculates a version for your project.